# How can I determine used libraries in a Delhpi 6 application (source available)

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

I have a fairly large D6 project I need to hand over to other people. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042588/how-can-i-determine-which-libraries-are-used-in-a-delphi-program-i-dont-have-th) except here, **all source is available**

However, I have made several experiments and tests over the years, and I have a fairly large amount of libraries, mostly open source. The other people only need required / used libraries.

What method would I use simplest to list all used libraries / units ? Something along this example:

```
Delphi project: myproject.dpr
Project path:   c:\data\mytest

Units:
   c:\delphi\lib\unit1.pas
   c:\delhpi\opensource\jcl\cryptmain.pas
   c:\delhpi\opensource\jcl\cryptmaininclude.pas
   c:\data\mytest\demounit.pas
```

Of course even nicer if I could know in which unit in my project the other libraries are used. But not necessary.

As far as I know, the D6 IDE does not offer to "package project" with every needed PAS or DCU, which is really I would be after.

The manual way would be to find as many as I can, then experiment and add until I can build.

Comment: GExperts has a "Project Dependencies" wizard that might be what you need.  I think the latest version (https://blog.dummzeuch.de/gexperts-documentation/) may only work with Delphi 7 onward, but older versions are also available at https://www.gexperts.org/download/

Comment: Compile the code and every time the compiler complains about a missing dependency that's one more. Properly configured projects inckude their dependencies in the revision control system.

Comment: You could let the compiler generate a map file. It will list all units from wich code was compiled into the exectuable. (Ressource only units wil. be missing though.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tool **"Pascal analyzer"** from Paganza Software (https://www.peganza.com).
It has a free version called **"Pascal analyzer Lite"**.
It parses Delphi or Borland Pascal source code. It builds large internal tables of identifiers, and collects other information such as calls between subprograms.

You can [see the online documentation here](https://www.peganza.com/PALHelp/index.html).

Include a **"Uses Report"** and a **"Third-party Dependencies Report"** among others, trhat can be usefuls for you.

Image of all reports that incklude this tools:

[image]